# Not in Swi-Prolog 6.2

Tags: prolog

I have this facts:

```
morpheme(a,82).
morpheme(r,83).
```

And i have this rule:

```
foo(er,Start) :-
    morpheme(a,Start), morpheme(r,I), I is Start+1,
    not(morfema(_,J)), J is I+1.
```

When I ask the query:

```
foo(er,82).
```

I got "false" (wrong answer) instead of "true" (correct answer).

In the query I've tried to say that: "if there is a morpheme AR in the start position "Start" and there are no more morphemes in higher positions (higher than Start+1), then fires the rule".

I tried using \+ and cut-fail (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850563/writing-prolog-statement-with-not-operator) but no success :(

I think that the problem is located in the way i wrote the rule.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo: morfema / morpheme.

But the deeper problem is the variable `J`: At the point in time when the negation is tried, `J` is an uninstantiated variable. Only afterwards, it gets the value you expect.

So exchange the two goals - and better use `\+` in place of not!

The `\+` means: not provable at this point in time. It therefore reveals a bit the way how Prolog programs are executed.

---

There is another problem in your program: You may move `I is Start+1` one to the left. In this manner the `morpheme(r,I)` will be a ground goal. It might be executed faster.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks False! That solved the problem. The modified code is below:

```
morpheme(a,82).
morpheme(r,83).

not(X) :- \+ X.

foo(er,Start) :-
    morpheme(a,Start), I is Start+1, morpheme(r,I),
    J is I+1, not(morpheme(_,J)).
```